How to derive to recurrence relation of binomial coefficients from explicit formula?
Suppose we only know the explicit formula for binomial coefficients $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and we want to find a recurrence for them.
Vice versa is of course easy:
\begin{align}
{ n-1 \choose k } + { n-1 \choose k-1} & = \frac{(n-1)!}{k! (n - 1 - k)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{(k - 1)!(n - k)!} \\
& = (n-1)! \left( \frac{n - k}{k!(n - k)!} + \frac{k}{k!(n - k)!}\right) \\
& = (n-1)! \frac{n}{k!(n - k)!} \\
& = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} \\
& = \binom{n}{k},
\end{align}
but finding it from the explicit formula doesn't seem to. How to derive to recurrence relation if we only know explicit formula?
Edit. Something similar would be searching for recurrence relation for the number of variations $V_{n}^{k}$ (choosing $k$ objects from $n$ different objects such that the order of k elements matters). The explicit formula for them is $V_{n}^{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

Is your question same as solving for $S(n,k)$ where $S(n-1,k)+S(n-1,k-1)=S(n,k)$ for $n-1\ge k\ge1$? Do you impose any extra conditions

@AngaeMT I am asking for binomial coefficients with $n$ and $k$ $\geq 0$. I do not really understand your first question. I am interested in how to find a recurrence for binomial coefficients when knowing olny explicit formula.

What about reading your identities bottom-up?

@Alezigl I thought your idea is to solve for a two-variable function $S(n,k)$ which satisfies the above recursive relation, because without the explicit formula, then the binomial coefficients would be possibly just a two-variable function. So thats why I ask if you have any extra conditions like $S(0,0)=1$ or $S(n,0)=1$ because I want to know your Definition of "Binomial coefficients" in this case.

@AngaeMT Oh, yes, of course. The extra conditions are ones that you have already written down. Thank you.

@Taroccoesbrocco I have already tried that but it didn't work because if I read these equations bottom-up I already know what is their recurrence. But I am interested in how to find the recurrrece from explicit formula if I don't know anything about explicit formula.

The monograph $A=B$ by Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf, and Doron Zeilberger, especially in Chapter 2, contains effective algorithms that establish hypergeometric identities.

The generating function for the binomial coefficients is $$F(t,z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}t^k\frac{z^n}{n!}=e^{(1+t)z}.$$
This satisfies the easily noticable recurrence relation $$\dfrac{dF(t,z)}{dz}=(1+t)F(t,z).$$
Translating back to binomial terms, this is exactly $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$.
One would be tempted to call this a cheap trick (maybe, it is). But for a lot of numbers, generating functions were known way before the recurrence relations. Building recurrence relations from generating functions is a tried and tested method. For example, see the Eulerian number for involutions.

After I wrote this, I realised that there is the much easier $F_n(t)=\sum_{0\le k\le n} \binom{n}{k}t^k=(1+t)^n$.
This leads to $F_n(t)=(1+t)F_{n-1}(t),$ which is precisely what we want.

For example, for the numbers $V_n^k$, we can use the generating function $$\sum V_n^k\frac{t^k}{k!}=(1+t)^n$$
We get $$kV_{n-1}^{k-1}+V_{n-1}^k=V_n^k.$$

Umesh Shankar +1, thank you for the answer. Only a question: can we derive to the generating function using only explicit formula?

It might not be very clean but a generating function is a formal power series and always exists. It depends on the explicit formula. Sometimes, an ordinary generating function might work. Sometimes, an exponential generating function might work.

Thank you for your reply.

@Alezigl I have added a bit more to the answer. Hope it helps.

It does, thank you very much!

@UmeshShankar   Clever! +1

We can try to reduce ${n\choose k}$ with $n\ge 1$ and $0\le k<n$ to previous binomial coefficients as follows.
We have ${n\choose k}=\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.
Now we want to replace $n!$ by $(n-1)!$  in the numerator.
But then the sum of parameters in the denominator should be $n-1$ instead of $n$.
Let us try to ensure this. We have
$$\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}=$$
$$\lambda\cdot \frac{n}{k}\cdot \frac {(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}+
(1-\lambda)\cdot\frac{n}{n-k}\cdot \frac {(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}=$$
$$\lambda\cdot\frac{n}{k}\cdot {n-1\choose k-1}+
(1-\lambda)\cdot\frac{n}{n-k}\cdot {n-1\choose k}$$
for some real $\lambda$.
The first try is to cancel $\lambda$ with $\frac{n}{k}$, so we try $\lambda=\frac kn$.
Luckily, then
$$(1-\lambda)\cdot\frac{n}{n-k}=\frac {n-k}n\cdot\frac{n}{n-k}=1.$$
Finally, we obtain
$${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}.$$

Alex Ravsky +1, thank you for the answer.
